# Why IntelliJ Idea doesn't create BuildConfig.java in AndEngine module's \gen folder?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, andengine

I'm trying to compile module (AndEngine), but Idea doesn't create `BuildConfig.java` file.

Module SDK is set to Android 4.0.3 Platform (java version "1.6.0_10")

\src and \gen folders are marked as "Source folders".

Comment: What IDEA version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Check the readme.md file in the AndEngine project. Nicolas says if your IntelliJ does not do that, that you can create it manually and put it in the Andegine source folder.

To quote that file

## AndEngine

### Building

#### Eclipse

- AndEngine has to be build with ADT-17 or higher!

#### IntelliJ IDEA

- AndEngine relies on ADT to auto-generate a "BuildConfig" class. IntelliJ IDEA (as of 11.1.1) has not fully integrated with ADT-17+. In order to build AndEngine with IntelliJ IDEA, you can simply add the following class yourself in the root package (org.andengine):

  ```
  package org.andengine;
  ```

  `public final class BuildConfig { 
      public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
  }`

Comment: IDEA supports BuildConfig since 11.1.2.

Comment: cool, I've never used it. I just wish Lem had mentioned it yesterday in his other question.