# Unable to get version name in code after moving to Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've just moved one of my Android projects over to Gradle, and as per recommendations inside the IDE and online I've moved all the configurations (min/max sdk, version name/code etc) into the build.gradle file.
Now a bug has been reported from a customer that where he could usually see the version name and code inside the product there is nothing.

After checking it out I've found out that the usual way of extracting those values has stopped working after I removed the `android:versionCode=""` and `android:versionName=""` tags from `AndroidManifest.xml`. I have verified that it works when these values are there.

Now I've been trying to search for a way of extracting these same values to use in code, but I have not found any reference to this behaviour else where (this not working like this).

The code I used to use to get the values was to simply extract them from the PackageManager as so

```
try {
   PackageInfo pInfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
   return pInfo.versionName +  " Build " + pInfo.versionCode;
} catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All hints, tips or solutions appreciated.

Comment: `BuildConfig` is what I meant in my answer. Don't edit to `Build`, please. Also comment if it's not working or doesn't suit you.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, but BuildConfig is not available for use since it isn't generated by Intellij (only seems to be generated by ADT in Eclipse). There exists how ever a class android.os.Build that contains 'Version' and 'Version_Codes' and before fully trying that out, I edited your answer because I thought you were talking about that class.
After trying to use it though I figured it wasn't correct, and was waiting for my last edit to be approved so that I could edit again to the original answer.
Edit: Seems that BuildConfig is a feature since IDEA 117.281 but doesn't work for me

Comment: I'm using AStudio also (Build 135), and it's working fine. I'd advise you to clean/rebuild your project or try re-installing AS.

Comment: Not using AStudio, using Intellij so will have to figure out why this isn't working. Rebuild/cleaning is of no help, sadly.

Comment: AS is actually built on IntelliJ Idea. Not sure why you would use plain IntelliJ. May want to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12387735).

Comment: Since AS is still in Beta I have not been willing to move production code creation to it yet. Testing and AS in side projects though

Comment: I have the same problem, the difference being that I'm using a library which uses the `PackageInfo` to retrieve the `versionCode` and `versionName` and I can't modify it to use the new `BuildConfig` generated by gradle. 
Is there a solution to this ? Can I somehow manually update the `versionCode` and `versionName` which will be later used from `PackageInfo` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `BuildConfig` class to fetch your version code which are defined in `build.gradle` file:

```
Log.e(TAG, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + " Build " + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
```